# Sum of values extracted using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an xml like the below.

```
<LPNDetail>
          <ItemName>5054807025389</ItemName>
          <DistroNbr/>
          <DistributionNbr>TR001000002514</DistributionNbr>
          <OrderLine>2</OrderLine>
          <RefField2/>
          <RefField3>OU01180705</RefField3>
          <RefField4>0002</RefField4>
          <RefField5>Retail</RefField5>
          <Qty>4</Qty>
          <QtyUom>Unit</QtyUom>
</LPNDetail>
<LPNDetail>
          <ItemName>5054807025563</ItemName>
          <DistroNbr/>
          <DistributionNbr>TR001000002514</DistributionNbr>
          <OrderLine>4</OrderLine>
          <RefField2/>
          <RefField3>OU01180705</RefField3>
          <RefField4>0004</RefField4>
          <RefField5>Retail</RefField5>
          <Qty>2</Qty>
          <QtyUom>Unit</QtyUom>
</LPNDetail>
```

I have extracted the xml  field using extract.xmltype and now i am getting the below result.

42

But i need to sum the quantity values i.e i need to get result as 6 (4+2).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shihaj

Comment: Post the query you used that got the "42" result.

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using? Oracle? Answers may vary across SQL dialects.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes

Comment: @Trioj Oracle DB

Comment: @jabbars looks to me like you are concatenating 2 string values rather than summing 2 numbers.  It is very unclear what tool/language/approach you are trying to sum.  In SQL you would say select sum(col) from tabl where ... .

Comment: @RogerCornejo  Hi Roger , I have a column having xml stored as clob in Oracle DB. In xml, there is a field Qty , i have multiple Qty in a single xml. so i need the sum of all Qty values. I have extracted the values from xml using extract and xmltype. But don't know how to sum the quantities. Hope you got an idea now.

Comment: @jabbars I can't give you a full answer [I am time constrained at the moment and your XML type, SQL ... not provided], but in SQL I've used xmltable to return the parsed out xml into a table structure that I can treat like an ordinary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "an xml". If it's supposed to be an XML document, you are missing the outermost tags, perhaps something like `<Document> ..... </Document>`

If your text value is EXACTLY as you have shown it (which would be pretty bad), you can wrap within such outermost tags manually, and then use standard Oracle XML tools. For the illustration below I assume you simply have a string (VARCHAR2 or CLOB), not converted to XML type; in that case, I concatenate the beginning and end tags, and then convert to XMLtype, in the query.

```
with t ( str ) as (
       select '<LPNDetail>
                    <ItemName>5054807025389</ItemName>
                    <DistroNbr/>
                    <DistributionNbr>TR001000002514</DistributionNbr>
                    <OrderLine>2</OrderLine>
                    <RefField2/>
                    <RefField3>OU01180705</RefField3>
                    <RefField4>0002</RefField4>
                    <RefField5>Retail</RefField5>
                    <Qty>4</Qty>
                    <QtyUom>Unit</QtyUom>
               </LPNDetail>
               <LPNDetail>
                    <ItemName>5054807025563</ItemName>
                    <DistroNbr/>
                    <DistributionNbr>TR001000002514</DistributionNbr>
                    <OrderLine>4</OrderLine>
                    <RefField2/>
                    <RefField3>OU01180705</RefField3>
                    <RefField4>0004</RefField4>
                    <RefField5>Retail</RefField5>
                    <Qty>2</Qty>
                    <QtyUom>Unit</QtyUom>
               </LPNDetail>'
       from   dual
     )
-- End of SIMULATED table (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution)
-- Query begins below this line
select sum(x.qty) as total_quantity
from   t,
       xmltable('/Document/LPNDetail' 
                    passing xmltype('<Document>' || t.str || '</Document>')
                    columns qty number path 'Qty') x
;
```

**Output**:

```
TOTAL_QUANTITY
--------------
6
```

Comment: I have xml documents saved in a DB field as clob. So i need to pick the same qty field value from multiple rows and sum it. how can i do that?

Comment: @jabbars - if the values all look like the one you posted, then the same query should work without changes. Did you try it? If you did and encountered problems, what were the problems?